# XMLSyntaxError when attempting to call method on Spyne server

Tags: python, spyne

At this point I've tested my Spyne server with suds and everything's working. My client has also successfully communicated with the server using SoapUI. With that set, we've moved out to the test environment for his application and, now, things are kinda messy. When he tries to send results from his test environment, he gets this error:

> senv:Client.XMLSyntaxError

I, on the other hand get an email with the subject:

```
[Django] ERROR: '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:vaul="vault.soap">   <soapenv:Header/>   <soapenv:Body>      <vaul:ReceiveLabTestResult>         <vaul:username>services_xxx_xxx</vaul:username>         <vaul:password>xxxx</vaul:password>         <vaul:result_xml><![CDATA[[DATA]]]></vaul:result_xml>      </vaul:ReceiveLabTestResult>   </soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>'
```

There are only two places in Spyne that raise an XMLSyntaxError and, based on the error, it seems that it's having trouble parsing the XML shown above. That said, I tried to parse this XML in exactly the same way it's being parsed in Spyne and it seemed to parse just fine:

```
In [21]: from lxml import etree

In [22]: parser=etree.XMLParser(remove_comments=True)

In [23]: root, xmlids = etree.XMLID(string, parser)
```

How do I get my Spyne server working with my client's test environment? Please let me know if you have any ideas. I've run out of 'em. Thanks!

Comment: I think this is more of a mailing list question as I can't have a straight answer for this type of question. What are the Http request headers?

Comment: Getting some info...I'll be back shortly. Thanks.

Comment: Please send an e-mail to soap@python.org as I don't seem to get e-mails for new comments here.